# How to display a long link in multiple lines via CSS?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor

These are codes:

```
<div>Hello World. <a href="http://www.newyorker.com/arts/events/2014/02/03/140203gofr_GOAT_front">http://www.newyorker.com/arts/events/2014/02/03/140203gofr_GOAT_front</a>.</div>

div {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gEDx9

This long link is displayed at 2nd line. I hope long this link can be displayed in multiple lines. I also hope this long link won't be displayed at outside of red `div` element. This long link should be fully displayed.

So this long link should be displayed at 1st line, 2nd line and 3rd line. May it will also be displayed at 4th line.

How can this be done via CSS?

Comment: `a {word-wrap: break-word;}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a CSS Property called "word-break" which you may find useful:

```
div {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Reference: [W3Schools word-break information](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

Comment: Quick note, you might want to avoid referencing W3Schools as it's known for misinformation: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Matt's answer can fix the issue. But I agree W3Schools is bad.

Comment: Good to know... I've used them pretty successfully as a reference a lot of times and didn't know that.  I have noticed some of their stuff is outdated sometimes, though.

Comment: as of this comment w3fools has re-endorsed w3schools.

Comment: "Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience. "

Answer (score 2):

Just add the word-wrap-attribute this way:

```
div {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhzKF/

Comment: This solution doesn't fix the issue. Link isn't displayed from 1st line right following texts "Hello World.". Matt's solution can fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to include a URL in page *content*, insert [zero-width space](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#zwsp)s at *permissible* break points. You can use the reference `&#x200b;` for them, e.g.

```
http://&#x200b;www&#x200b;.newyorker&#x200b;.com/&#x200b;arts/&#x200b;events/&#x200b;2014/&#x200b;02/&#x200b;03/&#x200b;140203gofr&#x200b;_GOAT&#x200b;_front
```

The details depend on the conventions on line breaks in URLs. The above example complies to the rules of *The Chicago Manual of Style*. There are other styles, too, but no reasonable style allows *arbitrary* breaking of URLs (which is what you would get by using `word-wrap: break-word`).

The proper handling of URLs in content is thus somewhat tricky, but it can be automated. However, it is best avoided by not using URLs in content unless the page content is *about* URLs. Normally, you should use links with descriptive link texts, “hiding” URLs into `href` attributes.

Answer (score -1):

apply this css to your A element

```
a { word-wrap:break-word; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `word-wrap:break-word`

**CSS:**

```
div {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gEDx9/3/